# What do the Android Voice names / codes mean?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am calling the `Voice.getName()` method like so:

```
Set<Voice> voices = tts.getVoices();
String name = voice.getName();
```

This returns code names rather than friendly display names. What I want is a display name, but there doesn't seem to be any way to get this.

Is it possible to translate the codes into something meaningful to create user friendly names? And to eliminate duplicates? A lot sound similar - but just a little bit different.

These are some codes returned for English UK:

```
en-GB-language
en-gb-x-rjs-local
en-gb-x-rjs-network
en-gb-x-fis-local
en-gb-x-fis-network
en-gb-x-fis#female_1-local
en-gb-x-rjs#female_1-local
en-gb-x-rjs#female_2-local
en-gb-x-fis#female_2-local
en-gb-x-rjs#male_1-local
```

My thoughts so far:

- Local and network do mean what you would think. However it is not clear if they are two versions of the same voice, as they sound a bit different (not very different though).
- The `rjs` and `fis` are repeated a lot, and apply to both male and female, but only for UK English. It appears that each language has one or two different sets of 3 letter initials - maybe it is a region code.
- You might think female1 and female2 would be different voice talent, but they appear to be just very slightly different expressiveness.
- I think `en-gb-x-rjs#male_1-local` and `en-gb-x-rjs-local` are identical
- All return same Quality of 400.

Does anyone have a better understanding of these?

Comment: I wondered the same myself, but I'm afraid I don't know the answer. What I have noticed, is that the names are changing - I had previously mapped the names to a gender, but after an update to the engine, it no longer worked....

Comment: Thanks for this. That is good to know that they could change in future.

Comment: @mike nelson have you got any more information about this?

Comment: @Kinjal No I didn't find anything more

Comment: @mikenelson What you mean by "Local and network do mean what you would think"? Does the "network" version only work online?

Comment: That was 6 years ago, I can’t remember what I meant! But yeah I think that’s probably what I meant

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be helpful, but for those of you not working directly with Android, and thus without access to an API that lists the voice codes, I've just found this URL on a forum thread which seems to list the URLs of the android TTS voices:

```
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/voices-list-r1.proto
```

Reading that as text (utf-8) gives some decoding errors, but it's enough to extract the codes:

```
en-GBGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/en-gb-x-fis-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice ����dBfemaleJen-gb-x-fis-phone-hmmP�X�`hen-GB #1x�$�
en-GBJhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/en-gb-x-fis-diphone-usel-r2.zvoice ؾ0���dBfemaleJen-gb-x-fis-diphone-uselP�X�`hen-GB #1x��
en-GBGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/en-gb-x-rjs-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice �0���dBmaleJen-gb-x-rjs-phone-hmmP�X�`hen-GB #2x��
en-GBJhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/en-gb-x-rjs-diphone-usel-r2.zvoice ��0���dBmaleJen-gb-x-rjs-diphone-uselP�X�`hen-GB #2x���
en-USGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/en-us-x-sfg-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice �*0���dBfemaleJen-us-x-sfg-phone-hmmP�X�`hren-USx�6�
en-USJhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/en-us-x-sfg-diphone-usel-r4.zvoice ��
   0���dBfemaleJen-us-x-sfg-diphone-uselP�X�`hren-USx���
de-DEGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/de-de-x-nfh-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice �"0���dBfemaleJde-de-x-nfh-phone-hmmP�X�`hrde-DEx�+�
pt-BRGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/pt-br-x-afs-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice ����dBfemaleJpt-br-x-afs-phone-hmmP�X�`hrpt-BRx�#�
es-ESGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/es-es-x-ana-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice �#0���dBfemaleJes-es-x-ana-phone-hmmP�X�`hres-ESx�.�
es-USGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/es-us-x-sfb-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice �*0���dBfemaleJes-us-x-sfb-phone-hmmP�X�`hres-USx�6�
fr-FRGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/fr-fr-x-vlf-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice �.0���dBfemaleJfr-fr-x-vlf-phone-hmmP�X�`hrfr-FRx�>�
it-ITGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/it-it-x-kda-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice �,0���dBfemaleJit-it-x-kda-phone-hmmP�X�`hrit-ITx�>�
ko-KRGhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/tts/v2/ko-kr-x-ism-phone-hmm-r2.zvoice �00���dBfemaleJko-kr-x-ism-phone-hmmP�X�`hrko-KRx�:
```

I still don't know what the codes mean, but at least this gives me the mapping between the language codes and the `fis`, `rjs`, etc codes, so it's a start.